# laravel route path become change when i am searching product

Tags: laravel

I am creating searching functionality in laravel it works fine for my first home page but when i am clicking on search and move on next page. In next page when i am searching the path became change and it will give error 404.. Why laravel route become change.

page load:autocomplete

After going to another page: productDetail/autocomplete,.../autocomplete what will do to avoid this situation.

Route:

```
Route::get('/getProduct','HomeController@getProduct')->name('getProduct');

Route::get('/getProductList/{id}','ProductListController@index')->name('getProductList');

Route::get('/productDetail/{id}','ProductDetailController@index')->name('productDetail');

Route::get('/autocomplete', 'ProductDetailController@fetch')->name('autocomplete');
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#product_name').keyup(function(){ 
        var query = $(this).val();
        if(query != '')
        {
         var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
         $.ajax({
          url:"autocomplete",
          method:"get",
          data:{query:query, _token:_token},
          success:function(data){
           $('#product_name').fadeIn();  
                    $('#product_list').html(data);
          }
         });
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
        $('#product_name').val($(this).text());  
        $('#product_list').fadeOut();  
    });  

});
```

header.blade.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var accessurl = '{{ route('autocomplete') }}';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/home.js')}}"></script>

   <form class="ps-search--header" action="#" method="post">
              {{ csrf_field()}}
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Product…" id="product_name">
              <button><i class="ps-icon-search"></i></button>
              <div id="product_list"></div>
   </form>
```

Comment: stop using relative URLs

Comment: `url:"autocomplete",` to `"{{ route('autocomplete') }}` in `$.ajax({})`

Comment: @lagbox solution plz

Comment: @KamleshPaul It will give error because i am creating separate js file

Comment: change that which i have mentioned

Comment: @KamleshPaul route changes as  http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20route('autocomplete')%20%7D%7D?query=s&_token=Dr0p30Donquh1e767uaSwEr9BYCvGEzDaUP0cFZK and it will give error  404

Comment: oh then try this `url:"/autocomplete",` on `/` add

Comment: @KamleshPaul Thank you sir you save my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use url `url:"/autocomplete"`

here `/` it represent root of your url `localhost/<root>`

so when you will in different page it will still search from localhost/autocomplete url